# Curious variadic non-type template parameter pattern

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, compile-time, non-type

I have working 'compile-time' code where a curious pattern keeps occuring. The simplest case is:

```
    template <int... E>
    struct SomeInts { };

    template <int... E>
    constexpr auto InvertF( const SomeInts<E...>& ) -> SomeInts<( -E )...>;

    template <typename S>
    using Invert = decltype( InvertF( S() ) );

    // use case:
    using X = Invert<SomeInts<1, 3, 3, 7>>;  // => SomeInts<-1, -3, -3, -7>
```

Straightforward enough. The detour via the function-template `InvertF` looks somewhat clever. I've never seen this before, so it's either genius or superfluous!

**Can this be simplified? How?**

Just my thoughts: If the `using Invert` template could extract an `E...` pack somehow, it could just be `= SomeInts<(-E)...>`. Smells like template template parameter, but I just can't get my head around this. The standard is probably to have a `struct` instead of `using`, but the matching/extraction issue remains.

Comment: did you write the code?

Comment: if it is not your code please add a proper reference

Comment: do you need license information, too?

Comment: it's simple enough. _partial specialization of alias templates is not permitted_.

Comment: Where would be the partial part?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization
Partial specialization is the "classical" way of taking a template parameter that has its own template parameters, and doing something with them (like invert does with those ints). This code is indeed pretty clever. This is how I'd normally do this with partial specialization: https://godbolt.org/z/G3q46W .